# Meaning of "you got your card punched by the number of the bodies you counted"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Quote from Wikipedia's article on [My Lai Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%E1%BB%B9_Lai_massacre):

> Vietnam was an atrocity from the get-go... There were hundreds of My Lais. You **got your card punched** by the numbers of bodies you counted.
> — David H. Hackworth[156]

What is the meaning of "got your card punched by the number of the bodies you counted"?

Is this a reference to [punch cards](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/punch_card) used at stores as part of loyalty programs? So, as you killed more people (counted bodies) your "card was punched" and in the end you earned a promotion or a medal?

Comment: I think your interpretation is generally correct.  I don't think he's referring to loyalty cards specifically, but more likely to [punch clocks](https://www.alliedtime.com/Traditional-Employee-Punch-Clocks-s/1477.htm) where an employee tracked their work time by inserting a punch card.

Comment: The idiom is: To get your card punched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one meaning to "get your card punched".
It can mean to die. *"Joe had his card punched in a fatal accident".*
It can mean to be fired from a job. *"After making too many mistakes the boss punched Joe's card"*
But in this case it probably means keeping a tally of the number of bodies you counted (killed?). Punching holes in some sort of card is a common way of counting usage (a multi-journey ticket) or purchases (a coffee shop loyalty card). So, unfortunately, your final interpretation of the meaning is most likely to be close to the truth.

Comment: It's not a particularly common usage with *any* of those meanings (which is probably why you haven't included any dictionary definitions; they don't exist). But I'm sure your interpretation here is correct - *the most important thing recorded in your Service Record is how many of the enemy you killed*.

Comment: I've never heard "getting your card punched" = being fired.  Got a source for that?

Comment: I don't think the cited usage is very good anyway. Why is it *number of bodies **counted*** rather than *number of "kills" (attributed to you)* ? Is the writer referring to some kind of "inspection team" who go round after any "enemy engagement" to count the bodies? I kinda doubt that.

Comment: Arguably it's a clumsy metaphoric allusion to ***clocking-on cards*** rather than "computer punched cards" anyway. In which case the figurative meaning is more like *The company only knows you exist and are on their payroll because you have to punch your card in every morning when you come to work*. Hence by extension, *The army only registers your existence because you're associated with a "body count"*.